# What is the difference between flannel (network layer) and ingress in kubernetes ?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, kubernetes-ingress

I am setting up 2 VPC on GCP, I setup kubeadm on each, let's call them kubemaster and kubenode1. So I ran kubeadm on kubemaster and kubenode1 which :

- `kubeadm init` on kubemaster
- `kubeadm join` on kubenode1

When I was trying to `kubectl apply -f (a deployment which contains a pod with simple webapps inside)` and `kubectl apply -f (a NodePort type of Service which target the deployment port)`

After that I simply access the webapps from my browser (on my local machine not on GCP), it just does not work as what I tried on minikube (I setup minikube with same kubectl apply as above too). I dig some search and there are a lot of people saying regarding Ingress and network layer (flannel in kubernetes website example)

My question is what are these Ingress and flannel ? Which one is necessary or both are not necessary at all if  I just want my webapp run ? How does each other works against others ? Because from my understanding the layering is as per below :

`Traffic -> Services -> Deployments/Pods`

Where are these ingress and flannel suits to ? If its not about them both, why my apps does not work as intended (i open all port in GCP setting so its not security issue I suppose), I tried setting up Kubernetes Dashboard-UI, run `kubectl proxy` and still my browser cannot access both services (my webapp inside the deployment and also Dashboard API), may be I am a little bit lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to add few more points along with exiting answers.

> After that I simply access the webapps from my browser (on my local
>   machine not on GCP), it just does not work as what I tried on minikube

Did you open the security rules/firewall rules for the `NodePort`? On which instance did you open and which instance are you hitting to access your app?

> My question is what are these Ingress and flannel?

I recommend you to read offical docs. But anyway, since you asked the question, I would like to tell few words.

- `Flannel` is a overrelay network for containers which the subnet for the container can span across multiple nodes(Which is opposite to native docker networking-host n/w, NAT, etc). Each containers gets it own IP every time it spawn. The `flannel` is more like control plain for container network which is internal to K8s

  - Highly recommend you to read [How Flannel N/W works](https://blog.laputa.io/kubernetes-flannel-networking-6a1cb1f8ec7c)
- `Ingress` is smart router for the load balancer(Or simple for now, we can say it exposes the application to out side of K8s). It works at application level. Once you hit the "Ingress" enpoint, it will forward to service(which depends on ingress rules) and then to app pod.

  - A blog on Ingress - https://medium.com/@cashisclay/kubernetes-ingress-82aa960f658e

I see you were talking about `ClusterIP`. Generally, the the `ClusterIP` is the IP for the K8s service which is nothing but a magic of "IP Tables Rules". `Kube-Proxy` is responsible to write ip table rules in every node once you define "Service". These ip table rules or `ClusterIP` points to actual pod IP(The IP assigned by flannel daemon). I hope you can understand, how flannel and "Ingress" fit into the picture or work together or responsible for application traffic.(*Please correct if I'm wrong..!!*)

- Can you paste ingress controller yaml content? What are the rules you defined?
- Since you are using GCP, why don't you try GKE? I mean it is easy to deploy, besides you can access your application with `LoadBalancer` instead of depending on `Ingress`(Anyway, its none of my business :-) )

Comment: https://github.com/archkiddo/kubetest , this is my whole setup its very simple, I just wanna make it accessible from outside network via browser

Comment: ok, so you didn't get any errors while creating Ingress/service/app? I believe, you are accessing the application like `<NODE_IP>:3000`??

Comment: no error, nope I am accessing `<NodeExternalIP>/` because you see the ingress route to root path, either way doesnt work

Comment: @thegexploit Right!. Can you check with `tcpdump` tool whether the packets are reaching while you hit the request in your browser. Also check the "Ingress-Controller" pod logs

Answer (score 2):

The flannel and the Ingress are completely different things.

flannel is a CNI or Container Network Interface plugin which task is networking between containers. As coreOS says:

> each container is assigned an IP address that can be used to
>   communicate with other containers on the same host. For communicating
>   over a network, containers are tied to the IP addresses of the host
>   machines and must rely on port-mapping to reach the desired container.
>   This makes it difficult for applications running inside containers to
>   advertise their external IP and port as that information is not
>   available to them.
>
> flannel solves the problem by giving each container an IP that can be
>   used for container-to-container communication. It uses packet
>   encapsulation to create a virtual overlay network that spans the whole
>   cluster. More specifically, flannel gives each host an IP subnet (/24
>   by default) from which the Docker daemon is able to allocate IPs to
>   the individual containers.

The Kubernetes supports some other CNI plugins: Calico, weave, etc. They  vary according to functionality ( e.g. supporting features like NetworkPolicy for restricting resources )

The Ingress is a Kubernetes object which is usually operate at the application layer of the network stack (HTTP) and allow you to expose your Service externally, it also provides a features such as HTTP requests routing, cookie-based session affinity, HTTPS traffic termination and so on. (just like a web server Nginx or Apache)

Comment: Do I need to have flannel ? because I thought container-container talks using ClusterIP service among them ? flannel is actually only connecting nodes to nodes. Do I need to have both ? or both are optional ? I still dont get it

Comment: Your nodes are connecting to each other via network interfaces (eth0, eth1, etc). `flannel` is not about connecting nodes to each other, is about containers network communication.  `ClusterIP`-  is not about pods, is about k8s `Service` object. You need more theory to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Said short, flannel or pod-to-pod networking layer in general, is what enables pods to talk to each other in Kubernetes. Ingress Controller on the other hand is what takes Ingress objects and turns them into rules for receiving and forwarding (mostly) HTTP(S) traffic to the backing services, over pod-to-pod network.

As you can see, technically, you need only the first one (pod-to-pod networking) as you can directly expose your service somewhere with NodePort or LoadBalancer service, it is very convenient though to use Ingress if you expose multiple services (pretty much like you do with vhosts on classic web server installations.